# Remove all text except the RegEx pattern (ABC|123|XYZ)(\w+) in Notepad++

Tags: regex, search, replace, notepad++

Multiple instances of the pattern that I am searching is exactly found by the following RegEx pattern: `(ABC|123|XYZ)(\w+)`

Using Notepad++ search and replace, I would like to delete everything else but these found pattern instances (separated by a newline), preferably in one run.

Is it possible?

Your kind help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why reopen? There are a lot of such questions. A sample answer can be `(?s)((?:ABC|123|XYZ)\w+)|.` > `(?{1}$1:)`.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment almost hit the nail. I included a newline in order to separate the matches: (?{1}$1\n:)

Comment: FYI, none of the 3 links that you provided allowed me to arrive at your answer, hence I don't think this topic is a duplicate.

Comment: It is the same answer, once you see how it is done, you may adapt it easily. You take your pattern and put it into the capturing group - `((ABC|123|XYZ)(\w+))`. Then you add `|.` alternative. Enable `.` matches newline, replace with `(?{1}$1\n:)` or `(?1$1\n:)`

Comment: Further, this regex search seems to be an equivalent: (?s)((ABC|123|XYZ)\w+)|.